# Spring WebFlux cache result Flux and reuse it

Tags: java, spring-webflux, flux

I have a use case where I need to cache the flux response and reuse it

For ex. here the, `invokeEndpoint` calls an external endpoint to get a response. Once I get the response I need to send the original response received and `aggregate`d response.

With the below code, the aggregate method also make the same endpoint call, which I'm trying to avoid since the request is heavy to get the response.

I tried using `cache` and `share` on the `data`, but it doesn't seem to working, I see redundant calls are being made which I'm trying to avoid.

```
private Flux<Integer> getResponse(List<String> requests){
   Flux<Integer> data = Flux.fromIterable(requests)
      .flatMap(this::invokeEndpoint, 10);
   //   .share(); // no luck
   //   .cache(); // no luck
   return Flux.concat(data, aggregate(data));
}

private Mono<Integer> aggregate(Flux<Integer> res){
   return res.reduce((a, b) -> a + b); //redundant call
}
```

The documentation is not helping much, any idea how can we cache and reuse the Flux?

Comment: This is not acceptable `Flux.fromIterable(requests)` -- `reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Flux<String> conforms to Iterable<? extends T>` Why would I want to look at an example that doesn't compile?

Comment: this is not an actual code, I just wrote to demonstrate my issue

Comment: can your `invokeEndpoint` return a `Tuple2` and then aggregate on it?

Comment: no, it can't return a `Tuple`

Comment: ok, can you wrap the result in a Tuple with the source?

Comment: sorry, I'm not getting, can you post the code?

Comment: @Saravana - Bogus question. No need to wrap a Flux in a Flux even in 'demo' code. No need to aggregate the Flux and put it as the last entry. By definition there is no last entry in a Flux. Bogus question.

Comment: @Saravana I mean `flatMap(req -> invokeEndpoint(req).zipWith(Mono.just(req)))`

Comment: @IgorArtamonov I can create a `Tuple2`, I need to return the actual response from the endpoint, and the aggregated response in the same Flux, for ex in the below code I would need to return `[1,2,3,4,5,55]`

Comment: ah, I misread that you need original request and aggregated response. if it's just response you don't need the Tuple of course and you can aggregate as is

Comment: take a look at the answer. in fact I used the `Tuples` anyway, but for a bit different purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can just keep the original value during the aggregation step, i.e. process them as pairs, and then concat both sides at the last step:

```
private Flux<Integer> getResponse(List<String> requests){
   Flux<Integer> data = Flux.fromIterable(requests)
      .flatMap(this::invokeEndpoint, 10);
   return aggregate(data))
      .flatMapMany(Flux::fromIterable);
}

private Mono<List<Integer>> aggregate(Flux<Integer> res){
   return res
       .map((a) -> Tuples.of(Arrays.asList(a), a)) 
       .reduce((a, b) -> {
           List<Integer> all = new ArrayList(a.getT1());
           all.addAll(b.getT1());
           Tuples.of(all, a.getT2() + b.getT2());
       })
       .map(ab -> { 
           List<Integer> all = new ArrayList(ab.getT1());
           all.add(ab.getT2());
           all;
       });
}
```

UPDATE: turns out the data needs to be produces as it comes in, followed by the aggregated result at the last item.

In this case a `scan` can be useful. But the main problem is that an addition message must be added at the last step. There are few ways, but it seems that in any case you have to keep it somewhere outside of the Flux flow.

One way is to utilize `doOnNext` and then `concat` it, like:

```
private Flux<Integer> aggregate(Flux<Integer> res){
   Tuple2<Integer, Integer> last = null
   return res
       .scan(Tuples.of(0, 0), (a, b) -> {
           Tuples.of(b, a.getT1() + b);
       })
       .skip(1)
       .doOnNext((a) -> { last = a; })
       .map(a -> { a.getT1(); })
       .concatWith(Mono.fromCallable { last.getT2() })
}
```

I'm not sure that `doOnNext` is a very reactor-like code, though.

So it could be also using the `materialize` and handling the `onComplete` signal to produce the aggregated value:

```
private Flux<Integer> aggregate(Flux<Integer> res){
   Tuple2<Integer, Integer> last = null
   return res
       .scan(Tuples.of(0, 0), (a, b) -> {
           Tuples.of(b, a.getT1() + b);
       })
       .skip(1)
       .materialize() 
       .handle((s, t) -> {
          if (t.getType() == SignalType.ON_NEXT) {
              last = t.get();
              s.next(t.get().getT1());
          } else if (t.getType() == SignalType.ON_COMPLETE) {
              if (last != null) {
                  s.next(last.getT2())
              }
              s.complete()
          } else if (t.type == SignalType.ON_ERROR) {
              s.error(t.getThrowable())
          }
       })
}
```

Comment: thanks @Igor, this approach may not help, since the reduce operation will be a synchronous, each element wont be streamed as and when received from endpoint method, rather it would be accumulated and streamed at once. What I'm trying to achieve is stream the data as soon as received, accumulate the streamed data as a very last element

Comment: it's not synchronous but it's an aggregation indeed, as it seemed that that's what you asked for

Comment: but if you want to produce the inputs before the aggregation result and don't keep them in memory I guess you can use `scan` instead of `reduce`

Comment: with `scan` or `reduce` redundant calls are made to the endpoint

Comment: I got it now, let me try. Thanks

Comment: yeah, I'm not sure yet how it could look like with `scan`, I guess it would require some additional steps, but it's probably the way that could solve your problem

Comment: @Saravana see an update with `scan` version

Answer (score 0):

Consider below code. Heavy endpoint is called once per every request. Responses are agregated at the end.

```
@Test
void test() {
    Flux.fromIterable(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
        .flatMap(this::invokeEndpoint, 10)
        .flatMap(response -> sendOriginalResponse(response).thenReturn(response))
        .reduce(Integer::sum)
        .as(StepVerifier::create)
        .expectNext(55)
        .verifyComplete();
}

private Mono<Integer> sendOriginalResponse(Integer response) {
    return Mono.just(1)
        .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("sending original response " + response));
}

private Mono<Integer> invokeEndpoint(Integer i) {
    return Mono.just(i * i).delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(5))
        .doOnNext(x -> System.out.println("invoke heavy endpoint for " + i));
}
```

Comment: I need to return both the actual and aggregated response, i.e. `[1,2,3,4,5,55]`, above code would just return `55`.